# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA honor user.language and user.country from Gradle config?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, internationalization, locale

I want to make sure my app always builds, runs tests, and runs using the correct locale, regardless of build & run platform.

So I have a simple unit test that checks that `new Locale("nb", "NO") == Locale.getDefault()`

Running the build with locale settings in either one of `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, `GRADLE_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS` works:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="-Duser.language=nb -Duser.country=NO" ./gradlew build
```

But I'm trying to avoid setting environment variables for every developer and build agent, so I tried setting these in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Duser.language=nb -Duser.country=NO
```

That doesn't work, since `Locale.getDefault()` now returns `en_US`.

I tried setting them in `tasks.WithType(JavaCompile)`, that doesn't work either:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += ['-Duser.language=nb', '-Duser.country=NO']
}
```

`tasks.withType(Test)` works however. Yay!

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += ['-Duser.language=nb', '-Duser.country=NO']
}
```

But now to the problem: IntelliJ IDEA still doesn't see the `-Duser.*` VM options, and the unit test fails there.

As a tip from @Andrej I tried setting the environment in `ProcessForkOptions` as described in [a JetBrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115426#comment=27-610182):

```
tasks.withType(ProcessForkOptions) {
    environment("LC_ALL", "nb_NO.UTF-8")
}
```

No success.

How do I make it honor the Gradle config?  Do I have to manually set the VM options in the Run Configuration for the test?

Comment: Try adding it for the task that creates new JVM process, like with this example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115426#comment=27-610182

Comment: @Andrey Good idea, but it didn't work, neither for command line building nor from IntelliJ

Answer (score -1):

As you can see at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2214, some system properties are not set properly if you set them via `org.gradle.jvmargs`. But using `systemProp.user.language=nb` instead works.

But even that only works when using Gradle to run. So you either have to change the IntelliJ run configuration to also set those system properties, or you have to use Gradle from IntelliJ to run the tests.

Comment: I tried setting `systemProp.user.language`, but it didn't work either :(

Comment: Where / How did you try?